# Was this patent ever granted?

Tags: patent-applications

In reference to the patent: [US20100118147](https://www.google.com/patents/US20100118147)

Was this patent ever granted?

Answer (score 1):

The european version (https://www.google.com/patents/EP2196967B1?hl=en) has been granted, the US version has been abandoned (https://register.epo.org/ipfwretrieve?apn=US.26893308.A&lng=en).